# Autoincrement end of filename if previous set of files exist

Tags: c#

I need to create x number of files (a set) but I must first check to see if the files exist with a similar name.

For example, tiftest1.tif, tiftest2.tif, ... exist and I must write tiftest again to the same directory. I'd like to append _x to the end of the filename, where x is a number that is auto-incremented, each time that I want to create the set. So I can have tiftest1_1.tif,tiftest2_1.tif, tiftest1_2.tif, tiftest2_2.tif, tiftest1_3.tif, tiftest2_3.tif and so forth.

Here is what I have so far:

```
...
DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(fileWatch.Path);
FileInfo[] exist = root.GetFiles(fout + "*.tif");

if (exist.Length > 0)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    do
    {
        cnt++;
    DirectoryInfo root1 = new DirectoryInfo(fileWatch.Path);
        FileInfo[] exist1 = root.GetFiles(fout + "*" + "_" + cnt + ".tif");

        arg_proc = "-o " + "\"" + fileWatch.Path
        + "\\" + fout + "%03d_" + cnt + ".tif\" -r " + "\"" + openDialog.FileName + "\"";

    } while (exist1.Length > 0); //exist1 is out of scope so this doesn't work
}
else
{

    arg_proc = "-o " + "\"" + fileWatch.Path
        + "\\" + fout + "%03d.tif\" -r " + "\"" + openDialog.FileName + "\"";
}
...
```

exist1.length is out of scope so the loop will continually run. I'm not certain how to correct this. My method was to originally scan the directory for a match and see if the length of the array is greater than 0. If it is > 0 then the _x will autoincrement until a match isn't found. arg_proc is a string used in a function (not included) which will create the files.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just reuse your `exist` variable?

```
FileInfo[] exist = root.GetFiles(fout + "*.tif");

if (exist.Length > 0)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    do
    {
        cnt++;
        DirectoryInfo root1 = new DirectoryInfo(fileWatch.Path);
        exist = root.GetFiles(fout + "*" + "_" + cnt + ".tif");

        arg_proc = "-o " + "\"" + fileWatch.Path + "\\" 
        + fout + "%03d_" + cnt + ".tif\" -r " + "\"" + openDialog.FileName + "\"";

    } while (exist.Length > 0);
}
...
```

This way, `exist` won't be out of scope.  It didn't look like you needed the original list of files once you started incrementing your counter, so if that is the case, you can just keep reusing `exist` to count your existing filenames.